# manipulate ISO 8601 datetime strings

Tags: python, datetime, google-api, iso8601

Working with python and Google's API , I'm trying to create and event with a duration of one hour. To do this I need to set a start dateTime and end dateTime using and ISO 8601 format, such as: `2017-01-25T06:30:00.000+0000`.

How would I go about taking a string such as that above and adding an hour, for example `2017-01-25T07:30:00.000+0000`. I've tried to dissect the string, convert the characters to ints/floats but that doesn't work (strips off the '0').

I should also say that this dateTime could be any value so many sometimes be `2017-01-25T21:15:00.000+0000` for example. In every instance I just need to be able to add one hour so that the event is created with a one hour duration. As an extra consideration, how would I handle events that start at say `2017-01-25T23:30:00.000+0000` As these would extend to the next day.

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to mess up directly with the ISO-formatted strings, there **will** be mistakes.

- parse the string with python-dateutil (`pip install python-dateutil`)
- it gives you a native python datetime
- add one hour to the datetime using timedelta
- reformat the result to ISO

```

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta

d_str = "2017-01-25T06:30:00.000+0000"
d = parse(d_str)
d2 = d + timedelta(seconds=3600)
result = d2.isoformat()
```